# How do I get my rails controller to work with a subdomain through Passenger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, configuration, subdomain, passenger

So this works for me in development mode, but when I attempt to deploy my rails app using passenger, my controller doesn't seem to be called.

I have set up a cname record for API to www.example.com. Also, I'm using Rails 3.2 and Ruby 1.9.3.

Here's the relevant portion of my `routes.rb` file.

```
# API
constraints :subdomain => 'api' do
  scope :module => 'api' do #:constraints => { :format => :json } do
    match '*skippydoo' => redirect('/'), :format => :html
    root :to => 'pages#developer', :format => :html
  end
end
```

Here's the Apache configuration:

```
# PassengerHighPerformance on
PassengerMaxPoolSize 12
PassengerPoolIdleTime 1500
# PassengerMaxRequests 1000
PassengerStatThrottleRate 120
# RackAutoDetect Off
# RailsAutoDetect Off

NameVirtualHost 10.28.124.130:80

<VirtualHost 10.28.124.130:80>

ServerName application.example.com
ServerAlias application

DocumentRoot /var/www/application/current/public/
<Directory /var/www/application/current/public>
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
RackBaseURI /
RackEnv staging

ErrorDocument 503 /system/maintenance.html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteLog /var/www/application/current/log/rewrite_log
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.(css|gif|jpg|png)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/system/maintenance.html -f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !maintenance.html
RewriteRule ^.*$  -  [redirect=503,last]

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 10.28.124.130:80>

ServerName api.application.example.com
ServerAlias api.application

DocumentRoot /var/www/application-api/current/public
<Directory /var/www/application-api/current/public>
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
RackBaseURI /
RackEnv staging
</VirtualHost>
```

This just renders some documentation I wrote describing my API.

I can switch the document root to some empty directory and get that render, so I know Apache is working correctly. The `application-api` directory is a symlink to my deployed application.

My API controller lives in `$RAILS_ROOT/app/controllers/api/pages_controller.rb`, but the one that is actually doing the work is `$RAILS_ROOT/app/controllers/pages_controller.rb`

```
Started GET "/" for 10.29.28.157 at 2012-04-26 21:12:51 -0500
Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (283.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb (4.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (5.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 522ms (Views: 394.4ms | ActiveRecord: 12.1ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
```

So, what gives? Why's it work in development but not production?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a VirtualHost for your www subdomain. Is Apache even sending the request to Passenger?

Perhaps you need to change your ServerName, or add another ServerAlias?

Comment: The virtual host is the second VirtualHost block there, for the api subdomain; there is no 'www' subdomain

Comment: I see. I was confused by your "www.example.com" reference. Here's a stab, change the :subdomain constraint to "api.application". If you look at ActionDispatch::Http::URL.subdomain you'll see that it would return both.

Comment: Alas, that did not work.  However, you did set me on the right path!

Answer (score 1):

So, I changed my constraints to be:

```
constraints :subdomain => /^api/ do
```

And it began working.  Now, why a regular expression would work and specifically naming the subdomain does not is a surprise to me!